# Extend vs += Behaviour

Tags: python

Help me understand the problem I am failing to identify in the following code.

```
def extend_a_list(list_var):
    return list_var.extend([6, 2])

def plus_equals_list(list_var):
    list_var += [6]
    return list_var

list_var = [1, 2, 3]
print "Extending"
print extend_a_list(list_var)

list_var = [1, 2, 3]
print "Plus Equals"
print plus_equals_list(list_var)


>>> Extending
>>> None
>>> Plus Equals
>>> [1, 2, 3, 6]
```

Extend is giving `None`. Why is that?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types - `extend()` does not return anything.

Comment: extend() changes the list in place but returns None

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Extend` returns nothing, it modifies the inputted list:

```
a = [1,2,3]
# a = [1,2,3]
b = a.extend([4])
# a = [1,2,3,4]
# b = None
```